# HTML/JS Login Form Issue

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I am having a problem with the functionality of my login form. I want to have any user press enter to check the form, which isn't working. It just submits the form to the url (url.com/?pswrd=password) instead of using the checkForm() function. It is done is HTML and javascript, and nothing is done serverside.

```
    <form onsubmit="checkForm(this)">
        <input id="password"
         type="password"
         name="pswrd"/>
        <input id="btn" type="button" onclick="checkForm(this.form)" value="Login" class="hvr-float-shadow"/>
    </form>
    </font>
    <script>
        function checkForm(form) {
             if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
             else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
             else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
             else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
             else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
             else if(form.pswrd.value == "[censored]") {
                window.location.replace('/indexproxy.php')
            }
            else {
                alert("Incorrect access code, please try again.");
            }
};
    </script>
<font face=arial color=white size=2>
<p>All access codes are CaSe SeNsiTIVE</p>
</body>
</center>
</html>
```

Comment: Please let us know exactly what is not working and how we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code example on the link below;

http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-action.phtml